# Disabling a Button to gray color-Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> Hi,   I am new to objective C.I have
>   created two buttons using interface
>   builder.Instead of writing two
>   UIButton actions I have pointed both
>   of the buttons to
>   -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;If i press one Button then the other
>   button should be disabled(showing gray
>   and should not allow to click).How to
>   set this.[button1 setEnabled:NO] will
>   do.But how to check which button has
>   been pressed.Is it like
>   (button.isSelected:YES).And How to
>   set that to gray color.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
        if ([myButton.isSelected:YES]) //Invalid receiver type BOOL
          {                            //No '-' method found //cast to pointer to  integer of different size warnings.
                [myEventLog setEnabled:NO];
                myTextView.text = @"Processing the request!!";
        }
}
```

> Processing the request doesnt get
>   printed on the UITextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sender` argument is the button that is sending the action.

```
 if (sender == myButton) {
       [myEventLog setEnabled:NO];
 } else if (sender == myEventLog) {
       [myButton setEnabled:NO];
 }
```

That's assuming that myButton and myEventLog are your buttons.

Comment: Thanks @Low France @Dmyto.It worked.How to set the buttons background to gray color.